# Sharing cache between two MVC applications

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to share cache between two mvc applications (both are rest services) running on the same machine - HttpRuntime cache does not work as the cache each runs in its own application space.

I've tried using System.Runtime.Caching but not having any success - would this approach work or would I need to look at memcached or something similar?

Comment: You can use Redis or CouchBase for centralized caching. Redis is very popular and mature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to share data between 2 processes or even app-domains using per-appDomain caching solutions (like `System.Runtime.Caching`).

You do need to use some external caching service (memcached is an option).